# Comparing two columns of data and copying third column

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to this and trying to build an automated spread sheet that compares two columns, A & C from Sheet2 and S & C from Sheet1. If the information is identical, paste the corresponding data from Sheet2's column D to Sheet1's column Z. I've been searching for days and found many examples, but none work for what I require.

One problem is that the data in both columns are very similar in nature. Ex. Sheet2.ColumnA will have 15 different numbers repeating and Sheet2.ColumnC will have a few series of numbers that may repeat. Basically:

```
If Sheet2.ColumnA1 & Sheet2.ColumnC1 = Sheet1.ColumnS1 & Sheet1.ColumnC1 
Then Sheet1.ColumnZ1 = Sheet2.ColumnD1
```

I can absolutely combine both data sets and would be left with: If Sheet2.(A1&C1) = Sheet1.(S1&C1) then  Sheet1.Z1 = Sheet2.D1, however, I am stuck on finding any combination matching, then copying the information.  Example:

```
A C     S C     D
2 34    3 55    Waivered
3 55    4 31    covered
5 12    5 55    Skittles
5 55
```

From the following list, I want "Waivered" and "Skittles" Copied to sheet 1.column(Z), rows 2 and 4, respectively.

Comment: Try doing a search for Index match

Comment: Suggestions to simplify your VBA task: first sort Sheet1 by column S, then col C, and sort Sheet2 by col A, then col C. In each sheet create a new (helper) column that will contain the concatenated values from the coresponding columns - these will now be the primary keys to be compared in a loop that will also copy the values from D to Z when the keys match

Comment: I can absolutely combine both data sets and would be left with: If Sheet2.(A1&C1) = Sheet1.(S1&C1) then  Sheet1.Z1 = Sheet2.D1, however, I am stuck on finding any combination matching, then copying the information.  Example:
A C     S C     D
2 34    3 55    Waivered

Answer (score 0):

If Sheet1 looks similar to this:

[image: Sheet1]

and Sheet2 like this:

[image: Sheet2]

This code (in a new generic module)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Copy3rdCol()
    Const S1COL1 = 19   'Sheet1, col S
    Const S1COL2 = 3    'Sheet1, col C
    Const S1COL3 = 26   'Sheet1, col Z

    Const S2COL1 = 1    'Sheet2, col A
    Const S2COL2 = 3    'Sheet2, col C
    Const S2COL3 = 4    'Sheet2, col D

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheet1
    Set ws2 = Sheet2
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, S1COL2).End(xlUp).Row       'last row on Sheet1, col C
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, S2COL2).End(xlUp).Row       'last row on Sheet2, col C

    If lr1 > 2 And lr2 > 2 Then     'Row 1 is Header row on both sheets
        Dim s1 As Variant, s2 As Variant, i As Long, j As Long

        s1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lr1, S1COL3))
        s2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(lr2, S2COL3))
        For i = 2 To lr1
            For j = 2 To lr2
                If s1(i, S1COL1) & s1(i, S1COL2) = s2(j, S2COL1) & s2(j, S2COL2) Then
                    s1(i, S1COL3) = s2(j, S2COL3)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lr1, S1COL3)) = s1
    End If
End Sub
```

---

will result in this (Sheet1)

[image: Sheet1]